# When is it possible to use the Parseval-Plancherel identity to solve an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, integration

The integral is of the form $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sigma(x)\mu(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.
Where the Fourier transform of the $\sigma$ function is $\tilde \sigma(p)= e^{-iap}\frac{1}{1+e^{-c|p|}}$ and the function $\mu(x)$ is given by $\mu(x)=-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x-2}{c}\right)$.

The Fourier transform of $\mu(x)$ can be found quite easily $\tilde \mu(p)=\frac{e^{-i p} \left(2 i \pi  e^{-\frac{c | p| }{2}}\right)}{p}$.

The question is:

Is it possible to use the the Parseval-Plancherel identity and write the above integral as
$\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \tilde\sigma(p)\tilde \mu(p)\,\mathrm{d}p$?

If so, the above integral becomes $\frac{i}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \frac{  e^{-i (a+1) p} \text{sech}\left(\frac{c p}{2}\right)}{p}$

Which looks like a Fourier Transform of $\frac{sech(\frac{cp}{2})}{p}$ function. How is this Fourier transform computed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the identity that Fourier transform of $K(x)=\text{sech}(x)$ is $\tilde K(p)=\pi  \text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi  p}{2}\right)$.

Using this identity the Fourier transform of $\frac{\text{sech} {x}}{x}$ can be easily computed

\begin{equation} 
\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} e^{-i x p}  \frac{\text{sech}{x}}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x= -i \int \pi  \text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi  p}{2}\right) \mathrm{d}p= -2 i \tan ^{-1}\left(\sinh \left(\frac{\pi  p}{2}\right)\right) \label{ident}
 \end{equation}

Using equation this relation, the given integral can be easily integrated

\begin{equation}
 \frac{i}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \frac{ e^{-i (a+1) p} \text{sech}\left(\frac{c p}{2}\right)}{p}=  \tan ^{-1}\left(\sinh \left(\frac{\pi (\Lambda_h+1)}{|c|}\right)\right) \label{rest} 
\end{equation}

Checking the answer numerically. [Plot: Constant a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uy8i.jpg) [Plot Constant c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uhnr.jpg)